# AngularJS : Load modal dialogue with dynamic template and data

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I try to do this but i didn't find what i needed.

I have a view like a list of movies or actor.
When i click on a movies or actor, it may load from my services additional data(working) and display some data from my services in my template view.

I try this code but it's not working

```
            vm.datasFullScreen = data.table;
            var htmlcontent = $('#divForModalTable');
            htmlcontent.load('angular/templates/template1.html');
            $compile(htmlcontent.contents())(vm);
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Don't try to mix jquery with angular, it is never a good idea. Instead, have a look at angular ui modal: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal to fix things properly, the 'angular way'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use Angular Material. Here is [Dialog demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog%20demo)

Comment: Is possible to generate data in this modal ? when i try the demo it's all the time static data template.

Comment: @Florian You can make custom dialog like this `$mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      templateUrl: 'dialog1.tmpl.html',
    })
    .then(function(answer) {
      $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
    }, function() {
      $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
    });`. Load Your data in DialogController and use callback functions to act upon users actions.

Comment: After some times it's working, but not for what i want, i can't get an element from my template with getElementById for exemple in my DialogController. how can i get an element ID in the template?
Thanks

Comment: Why would You use `getElementById` in angular?